# facing error while using sweet alerts in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sweetalert

i am trying to use sweet alerts in my application its working fine in all browser except IE (version 11).Following errors are coming when i call swal() function.

```
1.Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'.



2.   The value of the property 'swal' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

first error is coming from sweetalert.min.js and second is coming from my script where i am calling swal function.

Comment: where is codes? or page?

Comment: in my javascript file ia m calling swal method to show info and there it showing error. its a simple call like swal()

Comment: This works fine in IE 11 http://jsfiddle.net/sb5p5o2f/1/

Comment: Thanks @Michael for quick reply, my browser was running in compatibility view i changed it to edge and it started working.